# how to communicate between windows application and Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a very old application developed in Delphi C++. It has an api for which it has access to it. The application has given a sample source code in which there is a windows application which uses this api using Windows messaging system which is RegisterWindowMessage. Now I would like to create a interface to a silverlight. I have presently thought of exposing the data as a service using WCF and consume it in Silverlight. Is it possible or is there any other alternate solution to it? Kindly give me a suggestion as I am a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to communicate via WCF or better still [WCF RIA Services](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/) as Silverlight's security model won't allow you to communicate directly with another application on the client's computer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a possiblity you could use the COM interop in Silverlight 4 to work with the desktop app in that way.

This might help get you started:  http://elegantcode.com/2010/03/19/netdug-silverlight-4-com-interop-sample-code/